# Py2exe complains about missing dll when I have them?

Tags: python, module, numpy, py2exe

I'm getting an error when trying to build a python program into a Windows .exe using py2exe, and my program is not built. It says that I am missing some modules, such as numpy ones. I'm sure numpy is installed correctly. Why does it say that I have missing modules? How do I fix this?

```
*** copy dlls ***
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\py2exe\run.exe -> C:\Users\jchan1\Desktop\copdata\dist\dplotNew.exe
The following modules appear to be missing
['Carbon', 'Carbon.Files', 'Image', 'Numeric', 'Pyrex.Compiler.Main', '__svn_version__', 
'_curses', '_scproxy', '_transforms', 'configparser', 'copyreg', 'core.abs', 'core.max',
 'core.min', 'core.round', 'fcompiler.FCompiler', 'fcompiler.show_fcompilers', 'gobject', 
'mpl_toolkits.natgrid', 'nose', 'nose.plugins', 'nose.plugins.base', 'nose.plugins.builtin',
 'nose.plugins.errorclass', 'nose.plugins.manager', 'nose.tools', 'nose.util', 'numarray', 
'numpy_distutils', 'numpy_distutils.command.build_flib', 'numpy_distutils.command.cpuinfo', 
'numpy_distutils.cpuinfo', 'numpy_distutils.fcompiler', 'numscons', 'numscons.core.utils', 
'pkg_resources', 'projections.get_projection_class', 'projections.get_projection_names', 
'projections.projection_factory', 'pyemf', 'qt', 'scipy', 'setuptools', 'setuptools.command', 
'setuptools.command.bdist_rpm', 'setuptools.command.develop', 'setuptools.command.egg_info', 
'setuptools.command.install', 'setuptools.command.sdist', 'sitecustomize', 'testing.Tester', 
'usercustomize', 'win32api', 'win32con', 'win32pdh', 'win32pipe', 'wx', 'numpy.absolute', 
'numpy.arccos', 'numpy.arccosh', 'numpy.arcsin', 'numpy.arcsinh', 'numpy.arctan', 'numpy.arctanh', 
'numpy.bitwise_and', 'numpy.bitwise_or', 'numpy.bitwise_xor', 'numpy.bool_', 'numpy.ceil', 
'numpy.conjugate', 'numpy.core.absolute', 'numpy.core.add', 'numpy.core.cdouble', 
'numpy.core.complexfloating', 'numpy.core.conjugate', 'numpy.core.csingle', 'numpy.core.double', 
'numpy.core.exp', 'numpy.core.float64', 'numpy.core.float_', 'numpy.core.inexact', 
'numpy.core.intc', 'numpy.core.integer', 'numpy.core.isfinite', 'numpy.core.isinf', 
'numpy.core.isnan', 'numpy.core.log', 'numpy.core.maximum', 'numpy.core.multiply', 
'numpy.core.number', 'numpy.core.signbit', 'numpy.core.single', 'numpy.core.sqrt', 'numpy.cosh',
 'numpy.divide', 'numpy.e', 'numpy.fabs', 'numpy.floor', 'numpy.floor_divide', 'numpy.fmod', 
'numpy.greater', 'numpy.hypot', 'numpy.invert', 'numpy.isinf', 'numpy.left_shift', 'numpy.less', 
'numpy.log', 'numpy.logical_and', 'numpy.logical_not', 'numpy.logical_or', 'numpy.logical_xor', 
'numpy.maximum', 'numpy.minimum', 'numpy.negative', 'numpy.not_equal', 'numpy.power', 
'numpy.remainder', 'numpy.right_shift', 'numpy.sign', 'numpy.sinh', 'numpy.tan', 'numpy.tanh', 
'numpy.true_divide']

*** binary dependencies ***
Your executable(s) also depend on these dlls which are not included,
you may or may not need to distribute them.

Make sure you have the license if you distribute any of them, and
make sure you don't distribute files belonging to the operating system.

   OLEAUT32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
   USER32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
   IMM32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.dll
   SHELL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHELL32.dll
   ole32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
   WINMM.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
   fftpack_lite.pyd - C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack_lite.pyd
   COMDLG32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMDLG32.dll
   ADVAPI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
   msvcrt.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
   WS2_32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
   WINSPOOL.DRV - C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
   GDI32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
   MSVCP90.dll - C:\Python27\DLLs\MSVCP90.dll
   KERNEL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\KERNEL32.dll
   COMCTL32.dll - C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMCTL32.dll
```

Comment: Which version of python do you have installed?

Comment: Make sure that you are using the same version of python for py2exe and for everything else, i.e. that packages are installed in the same python version as the one you are using,

Comment: python and py2exe are probably not sharing your pythonpath. Check that numpy DLL's are in your path.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the DLLs in the Windows folder. Also copy the needed modules to the same folder as the one of the Python file you're trying to convert into exe.